# My label will not stay over the button in my learning game

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Is there a way in code to force the label to display on the top layer (in Swift) and not get buried by other elements?  I am not using Auto-Layout

I made a simple game whereby the screen advances down after every correct answer guessed.  However, the labels are supposed to stay "on top" of each row of 3 buttons.  What is happening is that the labels are getting covered by the buttons or partially covered as they advance down the screen.

Thanks so much

```
// if tile row is too low, move row to the top

if (WhiteTile1.center.y >= 601) {
    WhiteTile1.center.y = -71
    GreyTile1.center.y = -71
    BlackTile1.center.y = -71
    colorText1.center.y = -142
    word1 = wordarray[ofThree()]
    colorText1.text = word1
    colorText1.hidden = false
```

}

// colorText1 is the label .. WhiteTile1 , etc are the buttons.

Comment: Not enough info formation. How are you adding the items, IB or code? If code, what is it? Provide information.

Comment: i added some code, does this help?

Comment: No. Not really. Your variable names make it hard to know what we're looking at. `colorText1` should be an NSString from the name but it has hidden and text properties. If it's a label then call it a label. Also variable names should start with lowercase letters. Etc If `WhiteTile1` is a button then call it `whiteTileButton` (lowercase w). Also, why don't you just use the title property of the button? It's there so that you can put text onto a button. You don't need a label.

Comment: it is my first real programming project, so I didn't follow proper naming conventions.  I fixed the lower case issue now with find and replace.  Regarding the label, its because there is one label per row of buttons.  The label is the question, they tap the button to answer it.  Anyway, my issue is resolved thanks to PixelCloudSt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method that you are looking for is `bringSubviewToFront(UIView)`. If you are in the parent view controller it would look something like:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(colorText1)
```

Your strategy for calling that method to keep your UILabel on the top of your parent view's view hierarchy is entirely dependent on how you are going about things.

Comment: You're welcome!

BTW, since you're new to SO...people really dig when you accept an answer. It gives them reputation points, and is a way of saying "thanks for spending the time to solve the problem for me".  I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to the questions you've posted so far. The user, "The Tom", in particular, really went the extra mile. You, of course, don't have to do anything you don't want to, but you might consider marking correct answers to your questions as "accepted".  No biggie, just a heads up. Cheers! :)

Comment: As far as I can see...  my rep is not high enough to accept an answer, or if I can accept an answer, I do not know how.  Could you please enlighten me?  Thanks

Comment: my rep is high enough on math.SO and puzzling.SO .. and I have no problem accepting answers there.  However, I do not see any check mark that I can click on to accept your answer here on SO ..   Does my rep need to be higher to accept an answer?  I don't know.

Comment: ok, I accepted your answer by clicking on an invisible button where the check mark button should be.   I am running Safari on Mac Book Air, and literally, the button does not appear.. I had to click on blank area of the page under the votes number.  They should fix this.

Comment: Wow, that's a strange glitch. Can't blame you for not seeing an invisible GUI element...

Comment: yeah i started a question about it on meta , and it displays properly in Chrome, but in Safari it does not work, even when I clear cache and cookies.